# Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, google-play, bundle

[I tried to build the project in Android studio which I need to publish in Google Play bt it didn't worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC7o2.jpg)

I am having trouble building my Android studio project for publishing on Google Play.When I tried to build the project, I encounter an error and build fails.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully build my andorid studio project for publishing on Google play.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I finally got the answer. I deleted node modules from my project folder and installed once again by using command ( npm install ). After I restart my computer, Opened Android Studio - clean project - build. If it shows any other error like duplicate resources or something, take project folder - Android/app/src/main/res , except drawable folder, remove all other folders which name start with drawable. Clean project then build..it will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6A0.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).